Can Keycloak Client Scopes be used to provide additional user centric authorization for a frontend web app
Scopes are purely for authorizing clients, not users. In other words, the scope allows the client to invoke the functionality associated with the scope and is unrelated to the user’s permission to do so.
This additional user centric authorization is application logic and not covered by the Keycloak tokens, i.e. access token but is important for managing the user interface and user experience. For instance, is the user permitted to download the data that was retrieved by the client or perform other actions that are unrelated to the functionality that the client invokes, i.e., displaying reports in a dashboard.
Could Keycloak client scopes be used to facilitate this gap of providing additional user centric authorization? If so, what would the scope permissions naming convention be, as currently the convention is to use a combination of resource and action, i.e., configSet-WRITE.
We attempted to make use of the existing scopes, specifically scopes that are associated with resources but this did not address problem and creating additional complexity.
The expectation was to derive authorization policies based on existing application-level relationships, i.e., user centric authorization (in whichever form that is possible) and resources scopes, to make access decisions, making it the most suitable to handle hierarchical structures.
